# Linker error comes when implement Creative SDK for Image Effects in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, adobecreativesdk, image-effects

I want to implement image effects in my project.
So I am trying to implement CREATIVE SDK for this image effects.

https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageeditor/index.html

I have completed all steps which is mentioned in this above document. Also, I have take care of Other Linker Flags, Frameworks, Path of Frameworks and all other thigs.
But Still Getting Linker error.

[image]

Look forward to hearing your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that in project target - on your MAC/ Local Device folder, the required files are there. 
The problem you are facing is that Xcode is unable to link the _AdobeAuthManagerLoggedOutNotification.

Also make ensure that step 3, 4 are exclusively taken care of during installation.

3. Copy resources
   Make sure AdobeCreativeSDKImageResources.bundle is included in your target's "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase.
4. Add linker flags

Update your target's (or project's) build settings to include the following "Other Linker Flags":
-ObjC
-all_load

the order in step 4 is really important.

Comment: Yess, I am sure about that 3rd and 4th step. But when I add AdobeCreativeSDKImage.bundle, and run the project then this error comes. And you that this SDK is how much important for this implementation.

Comment: Have you cocoapods installed on your project. Also, try deleting your Other Linker FLags and then again add. Lastly, try all the steps of integrating again, after deleting the library and stash changes related. It might help

Comment: No Right now in this project I am not using cocoapods. Yeah many time I tried this. Delete my all data many times but always getting same error.

Comment: do git stash for changes done for Adobe Library, then again install. I had the same kind of problem, i got my code working by doing this method